# How to properly use a `Read()` method that writes into a fixed size buffer (here `TcpClient`)?

Tags: c#, connection, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am trying to read the data from a `TcpClient`, here is how I am doing it:

```
var client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
var data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder();
using (var ns = client.GetStream())
{
    while (ns.Read(data, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize) != 0)
    {
        dataString.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
    }
}
client.Close();
```

The problem is that my string does not have a length of 8192 (which is the value of `client.ReceiveBufferSize`) and because of that I am appending a lot of `\0` in my StringBuilder.

How can I get only the exact amount of data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int readCount;
while ((readCount = ns.Read(data, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)) != 0)
{
    dataString.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, readCount));
}
```

EDIT:

As mg30rg points out in the comments, this approach is vulnerable to clients that connect and then immediately disconnect.  It is better to check the `DataAvailable` property before calling `Read()`; otherwise the thread will apparently block indefinitely.

Also, the `Connected` property will apparently return `true` until `Read()` or `Write()` is called, so you won't be able to detect this situation by using that property.

Comment: Well, this solution seems bad since `NetworkStream.Read()` [tends to block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719256/networkstream-read-is-blocking) the execution if there is no data to be read.

Comment: @mg30rg The code in the question implies that there's nothing else to be done on the thread, so it doesn't matter if the thread blocks.  To put it another way, if we check the `DataAvailable` property, what would we do in the case where it returns `false`?

Comment: @phoog Act as we would if the condition of the *while* block returns *false* ?

Comment: @mg30rg Okay, let me rephrase.  Since we have nothing else to be done on the thread, we can (should) just block the thread while waiting for more data.  Otherwise, since we have nothing else to do while waiting, we'll be consuming processor resources repeatedly checking the `DataAvailable` property.

Comment: @phoog - Let me define my problem with your solution. (English is not my native language so I guess I'm not clear enough.) I had a problem recently with a not so trustworthy client which connected to my server then instantly disconnected. Since I was using a solution like yours my server froze and failed to answer any further client requests. I only pointed it out to prevent anyone falling into the same trap.

Comment: @mg30rg thanks for clarifying, that makes more sense.  Presumably DataAvailable solves this problem by returning false if the client disconnects.  This is another good example of how developers can get into problems by thinking only about the normal use case and failing to anticipate other possibilities.

Comment: @phoog - In addition - _I'm almost sure you are aware of this but some 3rd reader might not_ - the value of `TcpClient.Connected` will - _poorly_ - only be updated when `TcpClient.Read()` or `TcpClient.Write()` is called, so checking `TcpClient.Connected` is not the right way.

Comment: @mg30rg actually, I was not aware of that; thanks for adding it.  I have edited my answer to incorporate this information for future readers who may not be inclined to read the comments.