# networkStream.Read is blocking

Tags: c#

I'm writing a simple application which will connect with a server. However I want to send simple chat commands aswell (see `Console.ReadLine` below). However this script won't get to  `string Message = Console.ReadLine();` since it's blocked at `bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);`.

I want to continue this script, but if there's bytes incoming, it should process them (like it's doing now) and if no bytes are incoming, it should go through the script and wait for user input). How can this be achieved?

```
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                // Blocks until a client sends a message                    
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // A socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                // The client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }

            // Message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            // Output message
            Console.WriteLine("To: " + tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("From: " + tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));

            // Return message
            string Message = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Message != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(Message);
                clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                clientStream.Flush();
            }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try using the [DataAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx) property. It'll tell you whether there's anything waiting on the socket. If it's false, don't do the `Read` call.

Comment: The documentation says Read should return 0 if no data is available.  This is not true?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore, I think it will only return 0 if the other side closed the socket -- i.e., if there's no data and won't be any more. Otherwise, it waits until there's something to read.

Comment: the thing is I don't want my read thread to be `busy spinning`, and the `DataAvailable` is a non-blocking property. how should I deal with that?

Comment: @Timeless That's different than what the OP asked. You should Ask a new Question. (But I'll give you a hint: ReadAsync.)