# NetworkStream Read. Please explain behavior

Tags: networkstream

I am writing a client program using NetworkStream. This question is somehow related to [Networkstream read is blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719256/networkstream-read-is-blocking/10719399#10719399)

My question is: What is exactly the behaviour of NetworkStream read?

I have googled, and read microsoft documentation and my findings don't agree with what I found.

1) First I read that it was blocking. Ergo I thought if something happens to the server, it will wait for the server connect again and a message to arrive. But this is not true. When the server gets disconnected , it throws an exception.

2) Related to that, will read ever return "0 bytes read"? How? What does this exactly means?

3) Should I use the catch to retry connection or should I use the "data available" property?

Thanks for any help you can give me.