# NetworkStream Read when the server is closed

Tags: c#, networkstream

Reading [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx), it says that NetworkStream.Read throws a IOException when the socket is closed.

However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719399/4451521) and my own experiments, when the other side close the socket, Read actually returns 0.

Now, you can say, the documentation says "If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0.". Well, this seems to not be true, because when there is no data, the Read method just blocks.

So my question is:

Regarding NetworkStream and the following three scenarios... When does

1) it block?

2) it returns 0 bytes?

3) it throws a IOException?

NOTE: Please don't say "read the other answers". The other answers (*and* the documentation) are confusing and not clear, so the goal of this question is to *clarify* the differences between those three cases.

Comment: The Network stream work like any other stream as long as it is connected.  So the Read method blocks until data is available and will return immediately with any data that is in the stream.  If there is no data it will wait until data is available.  When the connection is closed it will return with zero bytes.  It will give an exception when the stream object is null.