# TCP Client becomes unreadable after server restart

Tags: c#, tcp

Code:

```
          while(true)
          {
                Int32 port = Convert.ToInt32(Port);
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
                Byte[] data;
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                data = new Byte[256];
                String responseData = String.Empty;
                //stream.ReadTimeout = 10000;
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine(responseData);
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
          }
```

I am reading data from remote server as TCP client.The following line of code waits. Until the data arrives.But it is still waiting when the after server is down.

```
 Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

When I add the following line of code, it stops reading after a while and constantly crashes.(Server open)

```
stream.ReadTimeout = 10000;
```

What I want is for the server to continue reading when it restarts.but it Doesn't keep reading.
What could be the reason.

Solved:
stream.ReadTimeout = 10000;
after reconnected.

Comment: @Alpovo - See this answer which talks about checking the DataAvailable or CanRead properties of NetworkStream _before_ making the call to Read. Perhaps consider using in conjunction with a timeout or look at the example on MSDN. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719256/networkstream-read-is-blocking  | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_NetworkStream_DataAvailable

Comment: Yes I know. I can only communicate with tcp client with my hardware.

Comment: Constantly crashes with what error? Things might be working how they should, you're just not handing the communication correctly...

Comment: stream.ReadTimeout = 10000; 
after adding this code
After about 30 seconds, the read operation does not take place.

Comment: You have to wrap your `.Read` call into try{}catch{}, catch appropriate timeout and continue.